# Java IO difference in reading streams

Tags: java, io, stream, inputstream

Could you help me figure out the streams. Why in the tutorials I find that when reading from a file, we use len != -1 (for example).And when reading from a stream and then writing to a stream, we use len> 0.What is the difference when reading?

PS The codes below are taken from examples

```java
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

```java
 byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    int length;
    while ((length = source.read(buf)) > 0) {
        target.write(buf, 0, length);
    }
}
```

**UPD**

[link1](https://www.baeldung.com/java-inputstream-to-outputstream)

[link2](https://www.baeldung.com/convert-input-stream-to-string)

[link3](https://attacomsian.com/blog/java-convert-inputstream-to-outputstream)

**UPD 2**

You can also look at IOUtils.copy and Files.copy They are different too

**UPD 3**

I read that the read method does not return 0, or the available number of bytes, or -1. Thanks everyone

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: the read method returns -1 at the end of the file, but in the second case, if it returns 0 to us, then we finish reading

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-inputstream-to-outputstream
https://www.baeldung.com/convert-input-stream-to-string
https://attacomsian.com/blog/java-convert-inputstream-to-outputstream#:~:text=Using%20InputStream.,-transferTo()%20Method&text=In%20Java%209%20or%20higher,stream%20in%20the%20original%20order.

Comment: Thanks for the source links. It’s even better to edit the question and include them there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)) for `InputStream.read(byte[])` says the following:

> If the length of [*the buffer*] is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned; otherwise, there is an attempt to read at least one byte. If no byte is available because the stream is at the end of the file, the value -1 is returned; otherwise, at least one byte is read and stored into b.

and

> Returns the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.

A careful reading of the above tells us that `read` will only ever return zero if the buffer size is zero.

The buffer size is not zero in your two examples.  Therefore `len != -1` and `length > 0` will have the same effect.